# UICollectionView scrollToItem Not Working in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm using a collection view, UICollectionView, and it works absolutely great...except that I cannot scroll to any particular item. It seems to always scroll to the "middle" is my best guess. In any case, whatever I send to scrollToItem seems to have no effect on the scrolling. I've put it in various locations throughout my view controller but with no success.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let lastIndex = IndexPath(row: messages.count-1, section: 0)
    self.messagesView.scrollToItem(at: lastIndex, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps by the time `scrollToItem` is called, the collection view hasn't loaded data yet.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at that code and see the value for lastIndex.  As @mag_zbc says, most likely when that code gets called (especially if it is the first time the view will appear. the tableview has probably not fully loaded.  Also, put the app in the background after the full table has been loaded, and then open it back up.  It will cause viewWillAppear to fire again, but the tableview will be fully loaded and you should scroll to that item.   If that's the case, you need to trigger the scrolling somewhere other than viewWillAppear.

Comment: I had considered those options as well. I even put in invalid rows and it crashes giving a specific error about the number of items and the specific row number being invalid. So I know it is getting called and processed. The debug from a breakpoint shows that the data is loaded (at least it knows the number of items accurately). The lastIndex is accurate. If I add "1" to lastIndex (which would be invalid) it crashes as it should.

Answer (score 39):

UICollection View has bug in iOS 14 with **scrollToItem**. In iOS 14 it will only work if collection view paging will be desable.
So i got a solution if we have to scroll with both manual and programatically.

**Specially for iOS 14 and above**

```
  self.collView.isPagingEnabled = false
  self.collView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: scrollingIndex, section: 0), at: .left, animated: true)
  self.collView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, this bug still exists in iOS 15, but the above fix solved it.

Comment: The problem still exists in iOS 16, this fixed it.

Answer (score 11):

You could try putting the scrolling code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` which should get called after all table cells are loaded, which means your messages.count should work. Also, make sure you only have a single section in your collection view.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.scrollToBottom()
}

func scrollToBottom() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let lastIndex = IndexPath(item: messages.count-1, section: 0)
        self.messagesView.scrollToItem(at: lastIndex, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

***Swift 5 / iOS 15***

I was facing the same problem, so I tried this one-line code and get it done.

```
// here we slect the required cell instead of directly scrolling to the item and both work same. 

self.collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(row: self.index, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .left)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, in case you want paging enabled:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = false
    collectionView.scrollToItem(
        at: IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0),
        at: .centeredVertically,
        animated: false
    )
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
}
```